# What makes up Node's baseline memory usage?

Tags: node.js

Running a simple program like...

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('node', ['-e', 'setInterval(function () {}, 1000);']);
```

...will result in two processes running with about 18mb physical memory allocated to them each. What makes up the bear shares of memory? I am trying to identify those parts in order to write a process implementation with less memory footprint.

It's clear that `process.memoryUsage()` yields at least some statistics, bu combined they don't make up the whole.